# Exporting a function in shell

Tags: function, shell, export

Please tell me how to export a function in parent shell (bash, sh or ksh) so that the function will be available to all the child process launced from the parent process?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/can-i-export-functions-in-bash

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The `export -f` feature is specific to Bash:

parent

```
#!/bin/bash
plus1 () { echo $(($1 + 1)); }
echo $(plus1 8)
export -f plus1
./child 14 21
```

child

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(plus1 $(($1 * $2)) )
```

Comment: is exported function available only for child calls? How to apply it to current bash session? like to .bashrc writing, but only for current bash instance...

Comment: @vp_arth: If you don't need the function in child calls, you don't need to export it. It's available in the current session either way (note that if it's defined in a file, you'll need to source the file rather than run it to make it available in the current session).

Answer (score 12):

In `sh`, it is **not** possible to export a function, as [noted by Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29239806/can-i-export-a-function-in-sh-bourne-shell).

Answer (score 5):

Functions are not exportable by nature. However you can export strings, so I have a little trick here:

```
func="$(typeset -f funcname)"
export func
```

To import the function, re-define it from the exported string:

```
# in subshell
eval "$func"
```

Comment: Standard warning about avoiding `eval`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278439/109669

Comment: This feels so wrong, but can’t put my finger on it. If typeset is invoked in a subshell itself, and returns the function, why can’t the other subshell access it also, in the shell you are using? Cleaner just to source the function definition from the subshell?

Answer (score 3):

**If you are using ksh or zsh:**

You can use the environment variable `FPATH`, wherein you can place all your functions.

If `FPATH` is set on an interactive interpreter, and a command or function is not found in the current shell environment or the `PATH`, the directories listed there are searched for the existence of a file named after the missing command.  If one is found, it is sourced in the current shell environment, and expected to define the function.

So, you can place all your functions in a location in `FPATH`, and child scripts will also be able to find it.

You can use the `autoload` command in shell scripts to load the functions you require:

```
autoload fun_a fun_b
```

**In zsh, `autoload` is required for `FPATH` to work.**  In `ksh` and its close relatives, I believe it simply causes functions defined in `FPATH` to override regular command in your PATH, as they would if defined directly.

Some details on `FPATH` and `autoload`:

- http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch29_13.htm
- http://users.speakeasy.net/~arkay/216-7.4KshFunctions.html

Answer (score 1):

If you create subshells with `( )` then they will inherit a snapshot of all the definitions, parameters, and shell variables.

If you execute them like programs then you can put the definitions in `.bashrc`.

If you are trying to spoof an existing script into executing a wrapper or substitution for a PATH command, then `.bashrc` will work depending on details of the execution. If not, you could instead execute a wrapper script that simply does a `.` or `source` of an include file that defines the functions and then does the same thing with the shell script with the commands to be substituted.

The wrapper script might look something like:

```
script=$1
shift
. include.sh
. $script "$@"
```

The idea is that the first parameter is the name of the real script and remaining parameters are the args, then the above script is run instead.

Comment: Could you please explain these with some coding example. I dont want to put my function in .bashrc

Answer (score 1):

```
declare -x -f NAME
```

More info

```
-f        restrict action or display to function names and definitions
-x        to make NAMEs export
```

Comment: Please note that this is **specific to `bash`**. (`ksh`'s counterpart to `declare`, `typeset`, has an `-x` option, but it only applies to _variables_, not functions; ditto for `zsh`).