# Checking whether a function is defined

Tags: bash, function, shell

I have a simple script to check if `rbenv` is a function, when I type:
`$ type rbenv | grep "rbenv is a function"`
into the shell, I get positive result, shell response is `rbenv is a function`
Then I want to do this in a script, so I write in my file:

```
#!/bin/bash
if  type rbenv | grep -q "rbenv is a function" ;
then
  echo "success!"
else
  echo "something went wrong."
fi
```

I can't get this working for me, the result of this script is `something went wrong.` I want to get this working properly, and maybe know if there is a better solution to do this task.
I have tried also this version of a script with no success.

```
if  [[ $(type rbenv | head -1) == "rbenv is a function" ]] ;
...
```

writing `type rbenv | head -1` in a shell gives output `rbenv is a function`. I don't know what I am doing wrong, please point out my mistakes.

**Partial solution** to this problem is to run in your shell `export -f rbenv` before running a script, but this isn't the way to do this right?
**FULL SOLUTION** Apparently, what I need is to repeat my steps from installation of rbenv, as it is to put before if statement:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

I want to thank everyone participating in the discussion for guiding me through the solution :)

Comment: Did you [export the function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885871/exporting-a-function-in-shell)?

Comment: how did you define `rbenv`? you need to export it to make it visible to subshells.

Comment: rbenv is a set of scripts for running multiple versions of ruby from here https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv and it's in my PATH if it's what you mean by exporting, but in my script just running `type rbenv` gives other result `rbenv is /home/simone/.rbenv/bin/rbenv` and exporting from my external script output `./rbenv_check: line 2: export: rbenv: not a function`

Comment: If it's a function, it can't be in your `PATH`. Exporting a function means saying `export -f rbenv`. See my answer below.

Comment: Before the `if` statement, put `set -xv` and `export PS4="\$LINENO`. Then, after the `if` statement, put `set +xv`. This turns on debugging and will show you exactly what is being executed an dthe results. As others have stated, you might not have exported your function, so it's invisible in shell scripts.  You can also simply put the line `echo "Checking function: $(type rbenv)"` and see what the output of that line is.

Comment: ok, but in my case I want to export this function from my script which is seperate to rbenv script, and yes output from exporting from my script gives `./rbenv_check: line 2: export: rbenv: not a function`, so that I cannot do this inside my script, but I want to accomplish this here. my thought is that when installing rbenv maybe the function will stay inside the script and only then I will be able to check this from inside this script, but I have started writing from this check, so that I will be sure that everything is correct.

Comment: What does "run all the commands inside the script" even mean?

Comment: ...I'm wondering if, perhaps, you want to be _sourcing_ the script in question rather than executing it as a subprocess -- in that case it runs in the same shell as its parent, so there's no need to export anything at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FULL SOLUTION**
Apparently, what I need is to repeat my steps from installation of rbenv, as it is to put before the if statement lines I have in my `~/.bashrc` on Ubuntu Desktop or `~/.zshrc` in Zsh shell or `~/.bash_profile` in any other Linux flavour with Bash

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

only then it will load full `rbenv` script into my rbenv installation script and I can check if it's a function with

```
if  type rbenv | grep -q "rbenv is a function" ;
then
  echo "success!"
else
  echo "something went wrong."
fi
```

better way to do this, as suggested by tripleee, is to use `[ "$( type -t rbenv )" == "function" ]` inside the if statement. I'm not the shell hacker, but it seems to somewhat more codish and reusable.

I want to thank everyone participating in the discussion for guiding me through the solution :)

Comment: You can also use, e.g. `[ "$( type -t rbenv )" == "function" ]`. This is a little cleaner, as suggested by @tripleee.

Answer (score 6):

My hunch is that you have not exported your function. Try

```
export -f rbenv
```

before running your script. This will make the function visible to sub-shells, such as those which are started when you run a shell script.

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, a better solution might be to define your code as a function in your `.bashrc` or similar instead of as a separate script.

In addition, your code could be made more robust. The output format of the message could change in the next Bash upgrade, or you could end up using Bash localized to another language some day.

```
case $(type -t rbenv) in
    function) echo Success;;
    *) echo Something went wrong;;
esac
```

(The change from `if test` to `case` is just personal idiom / evangelism, not a crucial modification.)

Comment: ok, now I see I need to export this whole rbenv script, a function to my child shells... but what to do if I want accomplish this whole test with exporting in an external script? I want to write installation script for rbenv and how do I check for being a function if I cannot export rbenv from my script (look up to my edited comment)?

Comment: I was looking for this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**TWO WAYS TO SEE IF A FUNCTION IS DEFINED**

**Method 1:**

```
if [ `type -t rbenv` = "function" ];
then echo "'rbenv' is     a function"
else echo "'rbenv' is not a function"
fi
```

**Method 2:**

```
if `declare -F rbenv`; then echo "'rbenv' is     a function"
                       else echo "'rbenv' is not a function"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

> ok, but in my case I want to export this function from my script which is seperate to rbenv script, and yes output from exporting from my script gives ./rbenv_check: line 2: export: rbenv: not a function, so that I cannot do this inside my script, but I want to accomplish this here. my thought is that when installing rbenv maybe the function will stay inside the script and only then I will be able to check this from inside this script, but I have started writing from this check, so that I will be sure that everything is correct.

This isn't an answer to your initial question, but about attempting to export your function from inside the shell script.

Export tells your shell to copy that item into subsequent commands. Since your shell script is already a sub-shell, your function doesn't exist. It's already gone. No more. You have two choices:

- The easy way: Export the function before you run your shell script.
- The hard way: This will take a bit of setup:

I take it your function is defined inside some file that's executed when you log in. Take all these functions that you want, and put them in another file. Let's say `$HOME/.functions`.

Now, anywhere you need these functions in subsequent shell scripts, *source* that file in the shell script:

```
if [[ -x $HOME/.functions ]]
then
    source $HOME/.functions
else
    echo "ERROR: The $HOME/.functions function definitions are missing." >&2
    echo "ERROR: This script is exiting." >&2
    exit 2
fi
```

You could put the following line in your `$HOME/.bash_profile` file too, so you have these functions in your default shell.

```
[[ -x $HOME/.functions ]] && source $HOME/.functions
```

Note that I merely source in the functions if found, and don't print out an error message and exit. You don't want to do that in your `.bash_profile` script. Otherwise, one error, and you won't be able to log in.