# How to export a function in Bourne shell?

Tags: function, shell, unix, sh

Is it possible to export a function in Bourne shell (sh)?

The answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885871/exporting-a-function-in-shell) indicate how to do so for `bash`, `ksh` and `zsh`, but none say whether `sh` supports it.

If `sh` definitely does not allow it, I won't spend any more time searching for it.

Comment: BTW, `/bin/sh` is POSIX sh (defined in the early 90s), not Bourne sh (defined in the 70s), on any remotely modern system; that applies to ash, dash, and the like, which are POSIX sh, not Bourne. That said, POSIX sh is more featureful than Bourne, so finding that something isn't present in POSIX is also indicative that it isn't present in Bourne.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

[The POSIX spec for export](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#export) is quite clear that it only supports variables. `typeset` and other extensions used for the purpose in more recent shells are just that -- extensions -- not present in POSIX.

Comment: It might be useful to add this explicitly to the [more general question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885871/exporting-a-function-in-shell)

Comment: But it is possible to export a function in some Bourne/POSIX shell compatible shells, right?

Comment: @jarno, ... Bourne and POSIX specifications are really very different -- if you want to test which one you're on, try using `^` as a pipe character, which Bourne allows but POSIX shells don't. Anyhow -- the only POSIX sh implementations you'll find supporting exported functions are ones implementing a large superset of the standard, ie. ksh and its spiritual successors such as bash.

Answer (score 2):

No. The POSIX specification for [`export`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#export) lacks the `-f` present in bash that allows one to export a function.

A (very verbose) workaround is to save your function to a file and source it in the child script.

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh --

function_holder="$(cat <<'EOF'
    function_to_export() {
        printf '%s\n' "This function is being run in ${0}"
    }
EOF
)"

function_file="$(mktemp)" || exit 1

export function_file

printf '%s\n' "$function_holder" > "$function_file"

. "$function_file"

function_to_export

./script2.sh

rm -- "$function_file"
```

script2.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh --

. "${function_file:?}"

function_to_export
```

Running script.sh from the terminal:

```
[user@hostname /tmp]$ ./script.sh
This function is being run in ./script.sh
This function is being run in ./script2.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

Eval it`s eviel, but you can use `eval` in some cases. Offcourse you should undestand what you do

```
#myfunc.sh
myfunc()
{
  #do somthing
}
```

```
#script.sh
eval "$(cat myfunc.sh)"
myfunc
```

Comment: How is eval+cat better than `. myfunc.sh`?

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# ###  Ex: export function and print for su
#
install_xxx () {  install xxx; xxx ;}
export -f install_xxx
su -c "export -pf; install_xxx"
#
# ### Ex: export string as function for su
#
Install_xxx='Install_xxx () { xxx install xxx ;}'
su -c "$Install_xxx; Install_xxx"
#
# ### Ex: export string for sudo
#
Install_xxx ()
{
sudo $SHELL -i <<-\ CMD
install_xxx
install
 CMD
}
# ###
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).