# Replicating `export -f` using shells other than bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

## Background

I have a line in a shell script (`my_functions.sh`) that exports a function for use elsewhere:

```bash
#!bin/bash

my_function() {
    echo 'whatever'
}

export -f my_function
```

This file is sourced by another script.

```
. ./my_functions.sh
```

I need to make `my_functions.sh` usable by `sh` rather than `bash`. At the moment `sh` does not like the `-f` flag of the `export` call:

```
export: Illegal option -f
```

## Question:

What is a `sh` compatible way of accomplishing behaviour like `export -f`?

Comment: See: [How to export a function in Bourne shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29239806/3776858)

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus. This is a duplicate; seems I just couldn't find the linked question earlier.

Comment: Why do you think the function needs to be imported? Simply sourcing the file ensures that `my_function` is defined in that shell.