# How to make the vim call function in .bashrc?

Tags: bash, function, vim

Environment: debian9+vim7.4.

```
   cat .bashrc
   add(){
        echo $(expr $1 + $2)
    }
```

Now edit a file in vim

```
add 1 5
```

Run it in command mode `:w !bash`,an error occur.

```
bash: line 1: add: command not found    
shell returned 127
```

1.add `set shellcmdflag=-ic`  in both /etc/vim/vimrc and .bashrc  and .vimrc .
2.reboot
3.vim test.sh
enter into command mode
:verbose set shellcmdflag

```
  shellcmdflag=-ic
        Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

4.input two lines in test.sh

```
ls
add  5  6

:w !bash     
a1.sh       test.py    
bash: line 2: add: command not found    
shell returned 127
```

How to make both two lines executed? 
[image]
[image]

`:execute '! source ~/.bashrc; source '.expand('%:p')` can make both commands: `ls` and `add` run.

After rebooting,
1.add function can't be called from `sh test.sh`?

```
sh test.sh
test.sh   #it means that ls command executed
test.sh: 2: test.sh: add: not found  #it means that add function can't be called from  /etc/vim/vimrc or .bashrc  or .vimrc.
```

2.add function can't be called from vim `!bash %`?

[image]

```
test.sh    #it means that ls command executed
test.sh: line 2: add: command not found  #it means that add function can't be called from  /etc/vim/vimrc or .bashrc  or .vimrc.

[4]+  Stopped                 vim test.sh
```

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to source your .bashrc? After any modification you have to run `source ~/.bashrc`, changes will be visible only in that console or all consoles after a reboot.

Comment: try to add `echo bashrc running` in your .bashrc file. When you open a new terminal, do you see "bashrc running" printed in your screen? When you run `:!...` in vim, do you do you see "bashrc running" printed in your screen?

Answer (score 16):

The problem is that Vim by default invokes a *non-interactive* shell, and `.bashrc` (where you've defined your `add` function) is only read for interactive shells.

You can instruct Vim to use an interactive shell:

```
:set shellcmdflag=-ic
```

This may make external command invocations slighly slower (due to the overhead in evaluating your Bash initializations).

Alternatively, you could define the function somewhere else, so it's always available (but there's no easy place like this; see `man bash`, esp. the `INVOCATION` section). Or turn the function into a separate script accessible from your PATH (e.g. `~/bin/add`).

Comment: Why add `set shellcmdflag=-ic` in /etc/vim/vimrc can't work?

Comment: Is it overridden later? Check with `:verbose set shellcmdflag?` In general, you should prefer user-configuration (`~/.vimrc`) over system-wide one; are you sure that `/etc/vim/vimrc` isn't overwritten when you update your system / Vim?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is your function is limited to an interactive shell to execute it you have to do like this

```
:!bash -ic "add 1 2"
```

Answer (score 4):

To add the line `export -f add`  in .bashrc file.

```
   add(){
        echo $(expr $1 + $2)
    }
    export -f add
```

Now `source .bashrc`,every method can call add function from .bashrc properly.

Comment: (see also [Exporting a function in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885871/exporting-a-function-in-shell))

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this should solve it for you. It's more of a workaround than an explanation of you problem but it gets the job done

```
:execute '! source ~/.bashrc; source '.expand('%:p')
```

I'm just manually sourcing bashrc before calling the command.
One possible explanation to your problem is if you are on a mac. As far as I know OSX don't source bashrc, they do source bash_profile though.

Comment: `:execute '! source ~/.bashrc; source '.expand('%:p')` can make it run,why other methods can't call add function properly?

Comment: the other answers are assuming that whenever you run your shell interactively your `~/.bashrc` will be sourced. It's a reasonable assumption, I don't know why it wouldn't. What we are doing here is explicitly sourcing this file. I wouldn't run my shell command interactively if I know that I don't need it. As having `.bashrc` sourced is all you need I suggested using this piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

> How to make both two lines be executed?

```
 ls
 add 5 6
```

This also works (with either `shellcmdflag=-ic` or `shellcmdflag=-c`) :

```
:w !bash -i
```

With this approach there is no need to include `export -f add`  in `.bashrc`.

> Why add function can't be called from vim with `!bash %`?

Assuming you have flags `shellcmdflag=-c` you can do:

```
:!bash -i ./%
```

which is quite similar to the answer of exe.