# Bash - Exiting script file not child bash command | Exit command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, kubernetes, scripting

I'm creating a bash script file for doing some operation as

```
1. Do some operations
2. Go inside kubernetes cluster (kubectl exec -it <pod> --bash)
3. Copying some files 
4. Connecting to mongo
5. Adding some data to collections
6. Exit from mongo -----------> step 1
7. Exit from k8s cluster -------> step2
8. Do some operations
```

**Problem :**
I'm getting problem in Exit command( step1 and step2). It is exiting from script file not from mongo or k8s cluster.

**What I have tried**

It worked if I'm passing all commands inside options "c" as below:

`kubectl exec -it <pod> --bash -c "echo text && exit"`

But If I'm using any function( which I created in script) with "c" options then it din't work.

```
test() { // some code }
kubectl exec -it <pod> --bash -c "test && exit" // couldn't find test
```

**Also -c option is not working with mongo command.**

Does anyone have any idea about it?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Duplicate of [Exporting a function in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885871/exporting-a-function-in-shell)